# Operate on columns in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Assume I have a dataframe `df` which has 4 columns `col = ["id","date","basket","gender"]` and a function

```py
def is_valid_date(df):
         idx = some_scalar_function(df["basket") #returns an index
         date = df["date"].values[idx]
         return (date>some_date)
```

I have always understood the `groupby` as a "creation of a new dataframe" when splitting in the "split-apply-combine" (losely speaking) thus if I want to apply `is_valid_date` to each group of `id`, I would assume I could do

```py
df.groupby("id").agg(get_first_date)
```

but it throws `KeyError: 'basket'` in the `idx=some_scalar_function(df["basket"])`

Comment: How working `df.groupby("id").apply(get_first_date)` ?

Comment: Wow... Of course!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) it working with each column separately, so cannot selecting like `df["basket"], df["date"]`.

Solution is use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with your custom function:

```
df.groupby("id").apply(get_first_date)
```

Comment: Might be one of the most stupid mistakes I've ever made....

Comment: @CutePoison - I think not, it is not mistake. This functions are similar and sometimes working same.